# about scheduling

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, ajax, schedule

Q:

I want to make a web application , this web application will be a (schedule system) contains all time tables for(a university)(entering events,showing the events at those times,change events .... and other actions).

**first** :please ,i ask about free good schedule controls for this task.(i want many of them to select the convenient for me).

**second** : i need help, recommendation,what is supposed to do to begin this task, and if there is any similar web applications for this.

**feel free to explain the ideas.**

thanks a a lot.

Comment: All the items you listed above can be done using a simle DB application where you store data and display based on the dates. What is the requirement along the lines of scheduling?

Comment: I know the very good Scheduler control from DevExpress, not free but not too expensive. I don't kmow any free one but you can google for it.

Comment: yeah there will be a data base , i ask about free schedule control for entering my events and control them with easy to use interface

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at FullCalendar (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/). It's a jQuery calendar with month, week and day views and support easy mouse editing of events.

It's not a server control, but it shouldn't be too hard to integrate into asp.net website.

I haven't seen any good server controls that are free. Telerik and DevExpress do have quite nice Scheduler components, but cost something.